# Why raise after an exception?

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

In a `try-except` block, I thought the purpose of this was to catch potential errors in the try block through exceptions, in order to keep the script running.

I've seen things like:

```
try: 
...
except KeyError as e:
   raise KeyError("Some message...")
```

Why would you do this?

I understand how try-except blocks work, but it seems like I'm unsure of when and how to use them?

Comment: It's a bit ironic, but your example shows exactly why one would do this. re-raising allows you to change the error text (in this case, it will be `Some message...` instead of `'<missing_key>'`), or even another exception type

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/332017/why-raise-an-exception-if-python-raises-it-for-me

Answer (score -1):

The purpose is to pass on the exception to the calling method so the Class responsible for giving information to the user can show for example an error Text.